# What is a bank?

Tags: consensus

When reading about Solana consensus, I ran across the word "bank", but haven't been able to find a good explanation of what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you might be referring to the term [bank state](https://solana.com/docs/terminology#bank-state)?
In Solana's architecture "bank state" is a snapshot of the ledger at a specific tick height*, representing the current status of all accounts and programs, including those holding (nonzero) native tokens.
Essentially it's a snapshot of the ledger's activities and balances (i.e all transactions and programs states) up to that particular point in time.

*Tick height: [Tick height](https://solana.com/docs/terminology#tick-height) is the sequential count of ticks (timekeeping entries) since the start of the ledger. Each tick marks the passage of time, and the tick height provides a reference point for the timing of transactions and events within the blockchain.